# ZF: ZEND_SUBFORM - how to make element name like list[id][name]?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, subform, zend-form-sub-form

I create elements for subform:

```
for($i = 1; $i<10; $i++)
     $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("[$i][name]");
```

But [ and ] will be deleted after dispatch page.

So how to setup name like list[id][name]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another Zend_Form_SubForm for each $i:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $subform = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
    $subform->addElement('text', 'name');
    $mainform->addSubForm($subform, $i);
}
```

Text elements will be named "1[name]", "2[name]", and so on. If you want them to be named "list[1][name]" then you need another level of subform:

```
$listform = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$mainform->addSubForm($listform, 'list');
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $listsubform = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
    $listsubform->addElement('text', 'name');
    $listform->addSubForm($listsubform, $i);
}
```

Comment: you only need 1 level of subforms, then for each element add: $name->setBelongsTo('name');

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$element->setBelongsTo( $array )
```

and in that $array you can define as many levels of [] as you need, you don't have to create for that many levels of subForms. You don't have to create for that even any subForms.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thx, I tried it. It doesn't seem to work:(
At the same time subforms in subform work perfectly

Comment: My fault, the syntax should be like that (without array):
_$element->setBelongsTo( 'level1[level2][level3]' )_ - works in 100%

Comment: Ok, thx. Will try it in the next project. I tried the way venimus has said, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why id doesn't work for Zend_Form_Element_File? I cannot set array for it.